# Displaying all logs in separate windows in ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nx6d.png)We have a requirement in which we needs to display [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsWkC.png) all logs in separate window in an ASP.NET Core MVC application.

I have attached the solution explorer structure for our application. Please feel free if any doubt. In our requirement all logs should be  available. Please help me in achieving it. I needs detailed step by step process to achieve it. Any help in this regards would be highly appreciated.

I have not tried and would like to know from where and how I should start so that I can achieve the expected output/result.

Comment: In your picture is an Asp.Net MVC project. Do you mean to output the log of this Asp.Net project in another Asp.Net Core project?

Comment: @Chen no, there is a functionality in that where uploaded document/folder can be renamed, deleted, Locked/Unlocked. Also details can be viewed. So No we needs to display every logs to the user, like who deleted the folder/document or renamed etc  in separate windows using C#.

Comment: @Chen, I have added an image in my post for your reference. Hope it will help you. Please fill free if you required further inputs. Thanks & Regards, Rajnikant